# IBM Worklight V6.1 JSONStore.init() interrputs application

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, jsonstore

I have a simple app with an http adapter. When I call `JSONStore.init()` many times the application gets the data and everything works fine, but maybe every 10th re-installation on the same device, the application interrupts in `JSONStore.init()`. Then if I touch the screen and hit any button, the workflow goes on only for a part. I can do this multiple times then the workflow finishes, too. This problem also appears if I manually delete the `JSONStore` data and reopen the app. It appears in iOS and Android.

Anybody an idea what causes the problem?

This is my Log:

```
06-27 09:22:48.619: I/CordovaLog(29490): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
06-27 09:22:48.619: D/CordovaActivity(29490): CordovaActivity.onCreate()
06-27 09:22:48.669: V/WebViewChromium(29490): Binding Chromium to the background looper Looper (main, tid 1) {42270e48}
06-27 09:22:48.669: I/chromium(29490): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
06-27 09:22:48.679: I/BrowserProcessMain(29490): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
06-27 09:22:48.689: W/chromium(29490): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
06-27 09:22:48.699: I/Adreno-EGL(29490): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL4169980)
06-27 09:22:48.699: I/Adreno-EGL(29490): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
06-27 09:22:48.699: I/Adreno-EGL(29490): Build Date: 02/04/14 Tue
06-27 09:22:48.699: I/Adreno-EGL(29490): Local Branch: 
06-27 09:22:48.699: I/Adreno-EGL(29490): Remote Branch: 
06-27 09:22:48.699: I/Adreno-EGL(29490): Local Patches: 
06-27 09:22:48.699: I/Adreno-EGL(29490): Reconstruct Branch: 
06-27 09:22:48.739: D/CordovaWebView(29490): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: HTC
06-27 09:22:48.749: D/JsMessageQueue(29490): Set native->JS mode to 2
06-27 09:22:48.749: D/CordovaActivity(29490): CordovaActivity.init()
06-27 09:22:48.759: W/com.worklight.androidgap.analytics.WLAnalytics(29490): TLF_configurator.enable was called, but the required Tealeaf libraries are not present in the classpath.
06-27 09:22:48.759: D/WLDroidGap(29490): New installation/upgrade detected, copying resources and saving new checksum
06-27 09:22:48.759: D/Whitelist(29490): Unlimited access to network resources
06-27 09:22:48.759: I/CordovaLog(29490): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
06-27 09:22:48.759: D/CordovaActivity(29490): Resuming the App
06-27 09:22:48.759: D/CordovaActivity(29490): CB-3064: The errorUrl is null
06-27 09:22:48.789: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(29490): Ignore this event
06-27 09:22:48.890: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(29490): Ignore this event
06-27 09:22:49.050: D/WLDroidGap(29490): no need to check web resource integrity
06-27 09:22:49.090: D/CordovaWebView(29490): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
06-27 09:22:49.090: D/PluginManager(29490): init()
06-27 09:22:49.090: D/CordovaWebView(29490): >>> loadUrlNow()
06-27 09:22:49.130: D/CordovaActivity(29490): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
06-27 09:22:49.210: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(29490): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/js/skinLoader.js
06-27 09:22:49.270: D/CordovaWebViewClient(29490): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
06-27 09:22:49.270: D/CordovaActivity(29490): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/skinLoader.html)
06-27 09:22:49.440: D/CordovaActivity(29490): onMessage(spinner,stop)
06-27 09:22:49.460: D/CordovaNetworkManager(29490): Connection Type: wifi
06-27 09:22:49.480: I/chromium(29490): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
06-27 09:22:49.510: I/chromium(29490): [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
06-27 09:22:49.520: E/qdutils(29490): FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO failed
06-27 09:22:49.550: D/CordovaNetworkManager(29490): Connection Type: wifi
06-27 09:22:49.550: D/CordovaActivity(29490): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
06-27 09:22:49.841: W/PluginManager(29490): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Utils.loadSkin blocked the main thread for 207ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
06-27 09:22:49.841: D/CordovaWebView(29490): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
06-27 09:22:49.841: D/PluginManager(29490): init()
06-27 09:22:49.841: D/CordovaWebView(29490): >>> loadUrlNow()
06-27 09:22:49.841: D/CordovaActivity(29490): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
06-27 09:22:50.191: D/CordovaActivity(29490): onMessage(spinner,stop)
06-27 09:22:50.201: D/CordovaNetworkManager(29490): Connection Type: wifi
06-27 09:22:50.201: D/CordovaNetworkManager(29490): Connection Type: wifi
06-27 09:22:50.201: D/CordovaActivity(29490): onMessage(networkconnection,wifi)
06-27 09:22:50.832: E/AndroidProtocolHandler(29490): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/default/images/favicon.png
06-27 09:22:50.842: D/CordovaWebViewClient(29490): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
06-27 09:22:50.842: D/CordovaActivity(29490): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/default/index.html)
06-27 09:22:50.952: W/ResourceType(29490): No package identifier when getting name for resource number 0x00000064
06-27 09:22:50.952: I/InputMethodManager(29490): [startInputInner] EditorInfo { packageName=com.ConferenceApp, inputType=0xa1, imeOptions=0x12000000, privateImeOptions=null }, windowGainingFocus=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@42556108, mServedView=com.worklight.androidgap.WLWebView{4252ae18 VFEDH.C. .F...... 0,0-1080,1845 #64}
06-27 09:22:50.982: W/PluginManager(29490): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Utils.writePref blocked the main thread for 19ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
06-27 09:22:51.032: D/WLDroidGap(29490): unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: null
06-27 09:22:51.032: D/WLDroidGap(29490): unregisterReceivers:Receiver not registered: null
06-27 09:22:51.102: W/dalvikvm(29490): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 31688: Lorg/json/JSONException;.<init> (Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
06-27 09:22:51.112: D/com.ConferenceApp(29490): Extracting zip file: featurelibs/armeabi/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
06-27 09:22:51.272: D/CordovaActivity(29490): onMessage(spinner,stop)
06-27 09:22:51.272: D/com.ConferenceApp(29490): Loading library using System.load: /data/data/com.ConferenceApp/files/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
06-27 09:22:51.322: W/PluginManager(29490): THREAD WARNING: exec() call to StoragePlugin.provision blocked the main thread for 49ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().
06-27 09:22:51.332: I/jsonstore-core(29490): Performing migration to JSONStore 2.0
06-27 09:22:51.372: I/wl.client(29490): WL.Client.init ENTERING
06-27 09:22:51.372: I/Database(29490): JNI_OnLoad called
06-27 09:22:51.372: I/Database(29490): JNI_OnLoad register methods 
06-27 09:22:51.382: D/NONE(29490): ondeviceready event dispatched
06-27 09:22:51.382: I/wl.client(29490): WL.Client onEnvInit ENTERING
06-27 09:22:51.392: D/NONE(29490): wlclient init started
06-27 09:22:51.402: D/NONE(29490): Read cookies: null
06-27 09:22:51.422: D/NONE(29490): CookieMgr read cookies: {}
06-27 09:22:51.422: W/NONE(29490): Your application is using the WL.OptionsMenu API. Note that, if your application targets Android 3.0 (API level 11) or higher, WL.OptionsMenu might have no effect, depending on the device.
06-27 09:22:51.432: D/NONE(29490): addDeviceIDHeader deviceIDSuccessCallback
06-27 09:22:51.432: D/NONE(29490): connectOnStartup finalizeInit
06-27 09:22:51.442: D/NONE(29490): before: app init onSuccess
06-27 09:22:51.452: D/NONE(29490): [JSONStore] Start...
06-27 09:22:51.462: D/NONE(29490): after: app init onSuccess
06-27 09:22:51.462: D/NONE(29490): added onPause event handler 
06-27 09:22:51.482: D/NONE(29490): wlclient init success
```

Comment: Got the same issue popping randomly sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are an IBM customer or business partner, you can open a [PMR](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507639) and make sure you include the following.

- Worklight version (there are more numbers after `6.1`, eclipse should tell you under installed software)
- **Code and steps to reproduce**, ideally you would do this in a new project with a clean workspace to rule out issues with your application code or other worklight features you're using.
- Logs (logcat and Xcode logs) when it works and when it doesn't
- Versions for the mobile operating systems where you tested fails
- Steps you took to *"manually delete the JSONStore data"*
- Make sure you're calling `WL.JSONStore.init` inside or after the execution of the `wlCommonInit` function inside the `main.js` file.

Someone from support should be able to provide assistance. If it turns out to be a defect in the code, someone from development will work on a fix.